# Edit Padding x-data-item-inner

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Take a look at the screenshot.

[image]

The coal and propane items are in a Ext.dataview.dataview using component for display.

Coal is highlighted in blue and green. Green is the padding of the < div >.

I found in the css (highlighted line) the said < div > and the css classes applied to the element.

I tried overriding those classes this way

```
.x-inner .x-data-item-inner
{
    padding: 1px 10px 1px 10px !important;
};
```

Sadly it did not work.  How would I do that?

Dataview Code

[image]

Comment: Can you instead post the selector you're trying to override?

Comment: I don't know what a selector is, nor how to find it. :S I don't want to only edit Carbon-item, I want to edit every item of the list.

Comment: Post the actual configuration of your data view.

Comment: What configuration, you mean the config explorer in Sencha Architect? The code behind the dataview?

Comment: I just mean the code that you're using to create the dataview. The screenshot you posted is essentially useless to see what you're actually trying to accomplish, IMO.

Comment: Update with the code, but since it's a framework my "object creation" code is not of much help.

Comment: Why not post your code instead of these images? What is your template? Have you tried to use `itemCls` instead of changing the existing Ext css classes?

Comment: I tried using itemCls, it does not change anything that is why I tried overriding the CSS classes. Why did I post those image... so that you could see every classes that were part of the problem and see exactly which padding i was trying to modify.  The question was asked in the light of obtaining an answer not someone complaining that it did not handed out exactly what he needed.

Comment: If you want help from random strangers on the internet, handing them exactly what they need to help you might be a better strategy.

Comment: Ask for it before complaining might be a better way to achieve some kind of teamwork. Anyway,if you need more code please tell me which part has my project is too big to be posted in full here.

Comment: Create a minimal set of code that demonstrates the problem. Make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Can you duplicate this effect in Ext without Touch?  If so, create a jsfiddle that shows your concerns more easily.

Comment: I dont know Ext, I don't use Ext. The code is quite simple I'm trying to override the class highlighted in the Debugger (screenshot) so that the padding is set to the value I wrote, but it does not work for padding, if I were to change the background in my class, the 'padding-area' would be that color, so I gues the !important is the problem even though it's loaded before my !important..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, there was a property very specific set to 10px padding that was overidding everything, and since it was a custom one, sencha put on the !important overriding any other !important because of the specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ";" at the end of your code like in your post code ? If yes, you have to remove it !

Bye !

```
.x-inner .x-data-item-inner
{
    padding: 1px 10px 1px 10px;
}
```

Comment: So the class is probably add with some JS. Look in the source code for the specific portion of code in your browser. Is that the same class ?

Comment: I tried to replace the css in the framework's css.
I can't even find it, too big and messy and they clearly love to use !important

Answer (score 0):

So,

Can you test with !important :

```
.x-inner .x-data-item-inner
{
    padding: 1px 10px 1px 10px !important;
}
```

Bye

Comment: Already done, still no result :S